# How can I re-install a module?

Tags: 8

I am creating on Drupal 8 module. I have used a custom table to store the data collected from forms.
Somehow during installation, tables are not created due to an issue in the install file. Now I have fixed the issue, and I want to install the module again.

How can I re-install a module?

From [this](https://drupal.org/node/2225029) and [this](https://drupal.org/node/1199946) discussions, I know the *Disable module* functionality has been removed.

Is there any other way to re-install a module so that its database tables are created?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module can also help here.

It makes a "Reinstall modules" page available at /devel/reinstall, which lets you re-install modules in bulk.

It's also worth mentioning Drush; `dis` (obviously) doesn't work any more, but `pm-uninstall` and `en` still do. And if you have Devel installed, you can invoke a reinstall with

```
drush dre module1 module2
```

Comment: Note that devel doesn't yet support Drupal 8's uninstall-only changes http://cgit.drupalcode.org/devel/tree/drush/devel.drush.inc#n115

Comment: I've started an issue to fix that https://www.drupal.org/node/2292425

Comment: I think all the answers posted here are incorrect. The original question is how to "re-install". This is not the same as how to uninstall and then install. All the scenarios here, sadly, do an uninstall which is a major step backwards for D8 as this will wipe the configuration for that module. I'm still looking for the correct answer of how to "re-load" the install config for a module (without uninstall).

Answer (score 10):

As you said "Disable functionality is removed from Drupal 8" ..

The short answer is - you probably are looking for the "Uninstall" tab found on the "Extend" (Modules) page /admin/modules/uninstall

There is no longer any grey area between a module being on and active vs off and "purged". "Disabled" is no longer a thing. **Uninstalling a module means removing all traces of it.**

Go to admin/modules/uninstall and uninstall module... Then enabled the module from modules list page. That should install the module again.

For Example ....

Before Installing Ban Module in Drupal 8 ... ban_ip module doesn't exist in database..

[image]
[image]

After Installing Ban Module in Drupal 8... ban_ip table is created and module cannot be disabled but can be uninstalled in admin/modules/uninstall

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now if you uninstall module.. Table will be removed from database and module can be installed again which will create tables in the database..

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such awesome explanation. I checked the list of modules in *uninstall* tab, but couldn't found my module. If you want to check code here https://github.com/mohit-rocks/messaging . Currently you can install module and settings related forms are coming.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1: Uninstall and Install again manually**

Using the Drupal UI:

- Go to the *Extend* page from the admin menu
- Go to the uninstall module page
- Uninstall the module you wish to
- Go to the *Extend* page again (where you have a list of modules)
- Install the module you just uninstalled

Using Drush (you should try it if you don't use it):

- `drush pm-uninstall MODULE -y && drush pm-enable MODULE -y`
- OR in short `drush pmu MODULE -y && drush en MODULE -y`

Replace MODULE with the name of your module.

**Solution 2: Reinstall using Devel module**

Assuming you have the devel module installed.

Using Drupal UI:

- Visit the path `/devel/reinstall`
- Re-install the modules you wish to

Using Drush:

- `drush devel-reinstall MODULE -y`
- OR in short `drush dre MODULE -y`

Replace MODULE with the name of your module.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to re-install (reload) the install config for a specific module you can use this drush command:

```
drush cim --partial --source=modules/custom/MY_MODULE/config/install
```

Comment: This got me excited but it doesn't work for me, I keep getting errors about the source dir not existing.

Comment: What is the your source dir? And i guess it would require that the module has a config/install dir. If it doesn't; then likely there is nothing to re-install for that module.

Comment: I tried relative and absolute paths to the dir, on my local machine and my VM. Module has config dir with yml files. Ended up using drupal console and config:import:single. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works you can try the below for Drupal 8.

1. Remove the problematic module files and it's folder

   - rm -rf modules/your_problematic_module
2. Remove the cached twig templates

   - rm -rf sites/default/files/php
3. Clear the Drupal cache

NOTE: Make sure to backup the code and Database before doing this